# How do I add Advice to "goto" byte codes in Byte Buddy?

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I'm building a system that needs to run 3rd party code in Java 8 Nashorn and I'd like to monitor / control CPU and memory use. I've got a Byte Buddy agent that adds advice around Javascript method enters and exits but because loops are compiled down to byte code, I need to also augment any goto bytecode that goes backwards. It doesn't seem like something it currently supports trivially, but I can imagine that it has the capability to do it. Should I use it or write the low-level ASM code to do it myself?

Comment: I doubt that this is within the scope of byte-buddy. Besides, instrumenting every backward branch sounds like a good recipe to actually create the resource overhead that you intend to control…

Comment: I'm unconcerned with constant overhead as the impact is possible to control. This is really about stopping uncontrolled memory and CPU usage. Having everything be a bit slower isn't really a big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the developer of Byte Buddy and I do not plan to support something like in-method byte code manipulation and here are the reasons:

For manipulating byte code within a method, Byte Buddy exposes its underlying ASM API which (to me) feels like the best way of dealing with such detailed editing. The `Advice` component makes some assumptions such as an empty operand stack and overridable frames for local variables besides the method's parameters. All this makes it non-trivial to port the `Advice` component to be triggered within a method rather than before and after it.

I consider to add some other component for replacing any in-method method call with a dispatcher invocation at some point (similar to Javassists limited in-method replacement) but not in the near future.

Comment: Thanks Rafael! When building an Agent what is the best way to drop down into ASM and write the low level code to modify the class? Currently I do something like this to install my Advice:

            .transform((builder, type, classLoader) ->
                    builder.visit(Advice.to(ResourceUsage.class)
                            .on(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith(":"))))

Comment: Thanks for your help. Got it working perfectly now. Byte Buddy is a great library!

Comment: @Rafael: The last paragraph sounds like a natural use case for `invokedynamic`…

Comment: @Holger I am considering this; however invokedynamic does not allow for any form of Replace.call(foo).with(bar) as Byte Buddy cannot assume to have any bootstrap method on the class path. The alternative would be to only allow delegation to a custom bootstrap method. Still thinking about how to approach this. Thanks for the hint!